# Google Chrome won't let me refresh using the Enter key

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

If I am viewing a web page and wish to refresh it by clicking the URL and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> then I have to press it anywhere from 3-10 times before it refreshes the page. Same thing if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to navigate to the URL box.

Firefox doesn't do this and as a web developer I find it frustrating because it makes me think my keyboard is broken when I am trying to test the browser's rendering and caching behavior when visiting a page normally vs. <kbd>F5</kbd>  vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

Has anyone else experienced this or have any clue as to when did Chrome introduce this "feature"?

Windows 10 x64

Chrome 78.0.3904.108

Comment: Can't reproduce the behaviour here with same OS and Chrome version. Any extensions installed?

Comment: @CaldeiraG Let me check. One thing I noticed is that if I leave the URL highlighted for about 1-2 seconds then I can hit Enter no problem. The problem arises if I try to hit Enter immediately

Comment: @CaldeiraG  Yep, [I have a few, hah](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZk0l.png). Incognito loads no extensions and does not exhibit this issue so I guess I need to do some disabling/deleting.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I disabled all of the ones I am allowed but the problem persists. I can only imagine that it's the McAfee stuff managed by my organization. The interesting thing is that my Firefox also has the McAfee stuff installed.

Comment: A link that [might help](https://community.mcafee.com/t5/Consumer-General-Discussions/Internet-browser-slow-to-load/td-p/465878). Other than that, I'm out of ideas

Comment: I've seen a bunch of complaints about McAfee making computers slow but mine is not slow by any means. It just feels like the Enter key keeps getting intercepted. Web browsing and reloading web pages in instantaneous as far as I'm concerned and I have zero patience for laggy computers.

Comment: Looks like the URL is being analysed before loading so it can verify it. That's why you get the 1-2 sec delay.

Comment: @CaldeiraG That's interesting. If I am manually typing a URL which I have never visited then I am allowed to hit enter as soon as I am done typing though. Anyways, if you'd like to take all the information here and apply it as an answer then I'd gladly accept it.